# confusing situations when `tf.constant` not displayed in `tensorboard`?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Below is the working code where some `tf.constant` get displayed in `tensorboard`, some don't.

However, I have no idea why those don't get displayed.

Could anyone help me out here? Thanks

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# tf.constant(value, dtype=None, shape=None,
# name='Const', verify_shape=False)


a = tf.constant([2, 2], name="a")
b = tf.constant([[0, 1], [2, 3]], name="b")
x = tf.add(a, b, name="add")
y = tf.multiply(a, b, name="mul")

# verify_shape=True, error if shape not match
# edge1 = tf.constant(2, dtype=None, shape=[2,2], name="wrong_shape", verify_shape=True)


# verify_shape=False, if shape not match, will add to match
edge2 = tf.constant(2, dtype=None, shape=[2,2], name="edge2", verify_shape=False)
# increase row by row, from left to right
edge3 = tf.constant([1,2,3,4], dtype=None, shape=[4,3], name="edge3", verify_shape=False)

# reassign works
edge2c = edge2
edge3c = edge3

edge4 = tf.constant(np.ones((2,2)), dtype=None, shape=None, name="shape22", verify_shape=False)
# increase row by row, from left to right
edge5 = tf.constant(np.ones((4,3)), dtype=None, shape=[4,3], name="shape43", verify_shape=False)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./log/01_tf', sess.graph)
    x, y = sess.run([x, y])
    sess.run(edge4)
    sess.run(edge5)
    sess.run(edge2c)
    sess.run(edge3c)

writer.close()
```

Comment: you do not have to use `sess.run` repetitively, actually it is storing all the events asynchronously to the event file. The graph will display without any difference even if you remove all the `sess.run`.

Comment: Thanks!  you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now.

To display any nodes in tensorboard, the nodes have to be used in an operation first. Being a `tf.constant` without involving in `add` or `multiply` or any other operations, won't be displayed by tensorboard.